# Trying out JDBC service with Google App Script

Tags: jdbc, google-apps-script

I'm planning to experiment a little with the JDBC service in Google Apps Script. The problem is that I don't have a database. I could use Google Cloud SQL, but this is not free, so I'm a bit reluctant to use it at this stage where I'm just going to experiment a bit. I will probably switch to it, once my experiments have worked.

Does anybody know a free database hosting which I can use with Google Apps Script, i.e., which allows remote access and has a fixed IP?

Comment: Google it. This is *not* about apps script or coding.

Comment: I did google it extensively, but with no success. This is indeed not about apps script or coding, per se, but it is a question that coders who have experience with apps script might be able to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to find a replacement database to use as well several months ago.
I am glad that I didn't because I believe there are numerous differences between a standard single IP MySQL database (access experience) at that of Cloud SQL via Apps Script.
It has been extremely reasonable... $10/month maybe.